# Michael Hartl’s Rails Tutorial Chapter 11 (Section 11.4.2 Image Validation and 11.4.3 Image Resizing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am completely new to RoR and I don’t know what I did wrong. Everything was fine until I work through chapter 11 section 11.4.2 and 11.4.3. Image resizing didn’t work and I couldn’t even upload photo anymore. Before that, the picture uploader still worked well. I was frustrated I copied and pasted all the code but it still didn’t work.

the error shown on localhost is like this (I can't post screenshot, too bad)

```
Errno::ENOENT in MicropostsController#create
```

if it has anything to do with microposts_controller, here is the code:

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Micropost deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, :picture)
    end

     def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

If we use cloud IDE, we should do something like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing
```

But I don't use it. I use terminal and Sublime Text. Is there anything I should do before getting through this section? 
Is there anyone who’s encountered similar issue before? What should I do to get this worked? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK `Errno::ENOENT` is about file not found. Are you trying to read a file that doesn't exist? write to a missing folder?

Comment: I am pretty sure I am not trying to read a file that doesn't exist. It's just there are some codes that don't work which I am still figuring out. I've been following the instruction carefully....

Answer (score 0):

He has a little footnote after that section which says:

> I got this from the official Ubuntu documentation. If you’re not using the cloud IDE or an equivalent Linux system, do a Google search for “imagemagick <your platform>”. On OS X, `brew install imagemagick` should work if you have Homebrew installed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got solved by installing the imagemagick gem in my linux system . you can do it by typing :

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

This link regarding the gem will help in detail : 
[minimagick](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick)

I hope this helped. :)